# Adding values to 2 drop down menu - Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Hello I tried adding values to the drop down menu in a for loop as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JAwxq/)
Here is the code for your reference:

```
      <div class="well carousel-search hidden-phone">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Choose Month 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id = "dd1" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Choose Month 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id = "dd2" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                </div>

            </div>
```

and the Javascript is as below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var d=new Date();
       var year = ["2013","2014"];
       var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];




      for(i=0; i<monthNames.length; i++)

          $("#dd1").append("<li><a href=''>"+monthNames[i]+"</a></li>");
      $("#dd2").append("<li><a href=''>"+monthNames[i]+"</a></li>");
  });
```

one of the drop down menu list shows a single value of 'undefined'. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your for loop need to have { } in order to also execute the line of $("#dd2")

```
      for(i=0; i<monthNames.length; i++)
      {
          $("#dd1").append("<li><a href=''>"+monthNames[i]+"</a></li>");
          $("#dd2").append("<li><a href=''>"+monthNames[i]+"</a></li>");
      }
```

Comment: Thats totally embarrassing :(